# investigate why tmux takes so long to restore with 'tmux a -d'

Tags: linux, tmux, ubuntu-14.04

I have been using tmux successfully on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine for a long time, but in the last week or so, when trying `tmux a -d`, it sometimes takes more than a minute to bring the session back.

How can I investigate what's happening?

Comment: Do your SSH connections tend to get cut off by network problems? Do you know what the `-d` option does, and have you checked if removing it avoids the problem?